# I wrote a simple code on python, but it doesn't work as intended can someone help me

Tags: python

This code will display an image where the 0 is going to be ' ', and the 1 is going to be '*'. This will reveal an image:

> ```
>    picture = [
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ],
>        [0,0,1,1,1,0,0 ],
>        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
>        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ],
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ]
>         ]
> ```

The image to be revealed should be:

> ```
>    *   
>   ***  
>  ***** 
> *******
>    *   
>    *
> ```

The code that I need someone to help me with:

> ```
>    picture = [
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ],
>        [0,0,1,1,1,0,0 ],
>        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
>        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ],
>        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ]
>         ]
>  row=0
>  col=0
>  picture[row][col]
>
>  while row<=5:
>
>  while col<=6:
>   if picture[row][col]== False:
>     picture[row][col]=" "
>     col=1+col
>   else:
>     picture[row][col]="*"
>     col=col+1
>
>   print(
> ```

```
    str(picture[row][0]) +" "+ str(picture[row][1]) +" "+
```

> ```
>   str(picture[row][2])+" "+str(picture[row][3])+" "+str(picture[row][4])
> ```

```
    +" "+str(picture[row][5])+" "+str(picture[row][6])
          )
```

> ```
>  row=row+1
> ```

What my code produces:

> ```
>   0 0 1 0 0 0
>     0 1 0 0 0
>       1 0 0 0
>       * 0 0 0
>       *   0 0
>       *     0
>       *
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few small proposals are suggested for reference.

1. you can use for loops when you know exactly how many times you want to loop
2. Use the ***is*** or ***not*** keyword to determine bool type data and ==

try this:

```
picture = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]


for row in picture:
    for col in row:
        print(" " if not col else "*", end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be scare to use nested for loops.

```
for row in picture:
    
    line = ""
    for i in row:
        if i == 0:
            line += " "
        else:
            line += "*"
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler method:

```py
for row in picture:
    for col in row:
        print(end=' *'[col])
    print()
```

Very short version:

```py
'\n'.join(''.join(map(' *'.__getitem__, row)) for row in picture)
```